# SSL certificate errors: insecure URLs and a form

Tags: php, html, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a website hosted on Hostgator and i bought a SSL certificate from them and i installed it but it's not completely installed because there are some insecure URLS and a form .

Here are the errors from whynopadlock:

[image]

Comment: You need to use `https` urls with a certificate.... are these all external urls? Same still applies, don't mix and match `http` with `https`

Comment: There's a *real* simple fix for this. You also didn't include any code at all here.

Answer (score 0):

simple, you have to change all http in https in your code

Comment: I'd agree to a certain extent but there is a real simple fix for this. This would also depend on how they're using their code (though).